# apt-get upgrade reports error removing nvidia-prime in Ubuntu MATE 16.04

Tags: apt, package-management, nvidia-prime

I am using Ubuntu MATE 16.04. I think I had some broken packages which caused `apt-get upgrade` to return the following error:

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 386704 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing nvidia-prime (0.8.2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/nvidia-prime.postrm: 79: /var/lib/dpkg/info/nvidia-prime.postrm: lsb_release: not found
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-prime (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-prime
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does `apt-cache policy lsb-release` report that lsb-release package is intstalled?

Comment: lsb-release:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
     9.20160110ubuntu0.2 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: You need to enable the standard software sources for your Ubuntu version in `/etc/apt/sources.list` to install lsb-release, What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: unfortunately the "software sources" is missing.
I am on ubuntu 16.04 : 4.4.0-140-generic.
How can i enable lsb-release from the terminal ?

Comment: i had opened the /etc/apt/sources.list, but its empty !

Comment: I added the instructions for creating a new empty sources.list file in the `/etc/apt` directory to my answer.

Comment: Yes i have added these repositories, its updating now but seems like the server is slow (!6Kb/s). will get back soon once it is completed

Comment: try to run `sudo dpkg --configure nvidia-prime`, if you still have a errors output, what the output of `lsb-release -cs`?

Comment: The --configure command gives the above error (Edit2)
"lsb-release -cs" command not found.

Comment: sorry mistaken written!!, what the output of `lsb_release -cs`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

lsb-release package is not installed, so you are getting an error message when `sudo apt-get upgrade` is trying to access it.

Download lsb-release_9.20160110_all.deb from the [official Ubuntu website](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/lsb-release/download).

Open the terminal, change directories using `cd` to the directory where you downloaded lsb-release_9.20160110_all.deb and install it with the following command:

```
sudo apt install ./lsb-release_9.20160110_all.deb
```

Create a new sources.list file.

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/apt/  
cd /etc/apt/    
sudo touch sources.list
```

Open `/etc/apt/sources.list` for editing in nano text editor with the following command:

```
sudo nano etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add the following lines to sources.list.

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse  
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse  
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
```

The instructions for using nano editor are always found at the bottom of every page. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file being edited. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.

Update the list of available software and fix broken packages.

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install lsb-release python3.5-minimal 
sudo apt install python3 nvidia-prime  
sudo reboot
```

If `sudo apt update` is successful, try to run `sudo apt upgrade` again.

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: @abbasi_ahsan did you installed `lsb-release_9.20160110_all.deb`?

Comment: Yes i have. 
lsb-release:
  Installed: 9.20160110
  Candidate: 9.20160110ubuntu0.2